# Can multiple if statements be used in a for loop?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop, if-statement

Is there a way to make a for loop iterate a list of strings by using some multiple conditions?. I am trying to build a for loop which should iterate each element of a list made of strings, but it looks like my for loop doesn't operate each condition to each iterable of my list.

For instance,

I have many strings which differs due to their own contents, E.g(DNA has 'T' instead of 'U', RNA has 'U' instead of 'T' and an unknow (UNK) which has neither 'T' nor 'U' or any other characters.

The input is `['tacaactgatcatt','aagggcagccugggau','gaaaaggcaggcg','guaccaguuu'.'acggggaccgac']`

The output should be the type of DNA sequence:

```
Result: DNA, RNA, UNK, RNA, UNK
```

I think my mistake is due to a misuse of break sentences in a for loop, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

This is what I get so far:

```
seq = list(input('Enter your sequence:').upper())

for obj in seq:
    if 'U' not in obj and 'T' in obj:
        print('Result: DNA')
        break
    if 'U' in obj and 'T' not in obj:
       print('Result: RNA')
       break  
    else:
        print('Result: UNK')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are stopping the iteration with the **break** statement.

```
seq = ['tacaactgatcatt', 'aagggcagccugggau','gaaaaggcaggcg','guaccaguuu',
'acggggaccgac']

upp_seq = [obj.upper() for obj in seq]

result = []

for obj in upp_seq:
    if 'U' not in obj and 'T' in obj:
        result.append('DNA')
    elif 'U' in obj and 'T' not in obj:
        result.append('RNA')
    else:
        result.append('UNK')

print(result)

# print: ['DNA', 'RNA', 'UNK', 'RNA', 'UNK']
```

Comment: What I get by avoiding the break statement is another kind of iteration, because it returns multiple Results, what it should retutn is just the type of string by following the conditions, maybe is because it's not iterating through each object in the list.

Comment: Do you want to print the results for each element in the list?

Comment: Yes, but just in one print sentence, e.g. Result: DNA, RNA, UNK, RNA, UNK.

Comment: What about store the result in a list? Check the update answer.

Comment: yes, it looks like working but im now try to fix the condition because the first iterable in the list should be DNA and the second one RNA. This is probably because of the else sentence, i think it's to hoarding

Comment: Your conditionals are ok. Was my error iterating over **seq** instead over **upp_seq**.

Comment: I think upp_seq must be defined first in order to iterate properly, because the sentence: upp_seq = [obj.upper() for obj in ****upp_seq****] is causing a problem because upp_seq is not definded

Comment: Corrected.  Should be in **seq** instead of **upp_seq**.

Comment: is working on your shell?, cause in mine what i get is a list like this: ['UNK', 'UNK', 'DNA', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'DNA', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'DNA', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'DNA', 'DNA', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'RNA', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'RNA', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'RNA', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'UNK', 'RNA', 'RNA', 'RNA', 'UNK', 'UNK']

Comment: I think its because of the input, in shell it looks fine but when i call the input doesnt work

Comment: Can you print what input are you getting?

Comment: im using seq = (input('Enter your sequence:').upper()) as an input caller, and y shell what i get is: Enter your sequence: and i introduce a list of strings but what i get is what i put in the last message